# Exception while reading from JSON

Tags: java, json

I have this code

```
JSONObject obj;
try {
    obj = new JSONObject(readUrl("http://dleel.ps/ss.txt"));
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    JSONArray array = obj.getJSONArray("data");

    for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length() ; i++) {
        if (array.getJSONObject(i).getString("link")!=null)
        System.out.println(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("link"));
    }
}
```

why I am getting exception when theres no link (JSONObject["link"] not found.) , what should I put in the if condition ?
also I tried using instead of getJSONArray , optJSONArray but the same

Comment: What exception? Please post the stack trace.

Comment: you can see the JSON file in the txt shown in the readUrl function

Comment: @Brain Roach java.util.NoSuchElementException: JSONObject["link"] not found.
it reads the first one , but it fails to read the second one because its null

Comment: @Salah: There's a *lot* of JSON there. Please do the work to find which bit of it is causing a problem, and also show us the exception you're having trouble with. Read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints for suggestions about how to write a good question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [getString()](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#getString%28java.lang.String%29) method throws exception if key not found.
Instead use the [has()](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#has%28java.lang.String%29) method:

```
if (array.getJSONObject(i).has("link"))
```

Comment: u might wanna accept it as the right answer, so it might help others with same problem :)

Comment: You can also use the .optString("link") method, which returns null if the string doesn't exist instead of throwing an exception.

Comment: @SurajChandran just a quick question , how can compare the getJSONObject(i).getString("link") with another string ?

Answer (score 2):

To test if a key exists use,

```
array.getJSONObject(i).has("link")
```