# Play Json throws exception when field is not populated

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have the following Reads object:

```
implicit val branchRead: Reads[BranchApplyRequest] = (
      (JsPath \ "act").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "st").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "nts").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "bk").read[Int]
    ) (BranchApplyRequest.apply _)
```

The problem is that when one of these fields doesn't come from the browser, I get an exception and the program fails. Ideally, the non present field will be available but undefined. How to achieve that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Play Framework 2.2.2 Scala JSON reads with undefined/null elements causing NoSuchElementException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22757649/play-framework-2-2-2-scala-json-reads-with-undefined-null-elements-causing-nosuc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `readNullable` instead. For example, if `act` is `Optional`:

```
implicit val branchRead : Reads[BranchApplyRequest] = (
      (JsPath \ "act").readNullable[String] and
      (JsPath \ "st").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "nts").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "bk").read[Int]
    )(BranchApplyRequest.apply _)
```

And of course your `BranchApplyRequest` would be like this:

```
case class BranchApplyRequest(act: Option[String], ...)
```